# How to rotate a selected edit not at center

Tags: modeling

I am a newb, I have spent the last half hour looking for this specific answer. Most of what I saw had to do with animation or rotation of an object. I want this selected part of the spout to rotate/bend at the 3d cursor along the x axis. I tried to "space bar" - "set origin to 3d cursor".. but I get an error that it cannot be done in edit mode. So, I set it in object mode but when I go to edit mode it has changed back to center.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow the steps as:

Select your point where do you want to set your origin, Hit Shift + S and select cursor to selected, as shown below:

[image]

Change your pivot point to "3D cursor" as shown below:
[image]

I hope it will be your out put:

[image]

Best of luck!